# Understanding Martin Farach's suffix tree algorithm

Tags: recursion, suffix-trees

I feel stuck at this point. I have spent several days trying to get my head around the algorithm, but both resources I have [1] [2] seems to skip over whatever details that would make me comfortable trying to explain/implement it. I'm going to hope that someone here knows Farachs suffix tree algorithm, but I'll link to the paper below.

I get the individual mechanisms of the algorithm, but I don't understand how to put it all together. By starting at the first step:

(1) Creating the odd tree requires sorting every character pair of the string, but the example used, namely `g = 121112212221` yields the "sorted" list `l = (1,2),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,1)`, and then taking the ranks of `l` yields. `g' = 2,1,2,3,4,3`. I can't see how `l` is sorted, or why it would help to sort it.

(2) Farach mentions that the suffix tree for `g'` needs to be computed recursively. Is this the only step of the algorithm that needs recursion?

[1] http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.4336&rep=rep1&type=pdf

[2] [https://www.amazon.com/Computing-Patterns-Strings-William-Smyth/dp/0201398397](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201398397)

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer but I hope this helps.

re :

> Creating the odd tree requires sorting every character pair of the string, but the example used, namely g = 121112212221 yields the "sorted" list l = (1,2),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,1), and then taking the ranks of l yields. g' = 2,1,2,3,4,3. I can't see how l is sorted, or why it would help to sort it.

Let,

$l$ - list

$g$ - ranks of elements of $l$ in $sorted(l)$

You can easily recover $sorted(l)$ using $l$ and $g$. You just put $i^{th}$ element of $l$ at position $g[i]$ in some new array $A$, like this,

```
for i = 0 to len(l): 
   A[g[i]] = l[i]
```

Fill out following $A$ to see it.

l = [3, 2, 4]

g = [2, 1, 3]

A = [ , , ]